# How to add library to Paragraph bundle using hook_preprocess_theme?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, paragraphs

I wanted to add a library to a specific paragraph bundle. I know I can do `{{ attach_library('my_theme/my-library-name') }}` using twig, but that means I have to create a file for each bundle. The goal is to be able to use just the `my_theme.theme` file to add the library.

**Question**

How to add library to Paragraph bundle using hook_preprocess_theme?

Here is what we tried, but it didn't work even after cache clear.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraphs(&$variables) {
  $elements = $variables['elements'];
  $paragraph = $elements['#paragraph'];
  if(isset($paragraph) {
    $paragraph_bundle = $paragraph->getParagraphType()->id();
    switch($paragraph_bundle) {
      case 'my_bundle':
        $variables['elements']['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_theme/my-library-name';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `$variables['#attached']['library']` instead of `$variables['elements']['#attached']['library']`.

The code shown in the question becomes the following one.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraphs(&$variables) {
  $elements = $variables['elements'];
  $paragraph = $elements['#paragraph'];

  if (isset($paragraph)) {
    $paragraph_bundle = $paragraph->getParagraphType()->id();
    switch($paragraph_bundle) {
      case 'my_bundle':
        $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_theme/my-library-name';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in a preprocess hook the top level is the only supported place to add attachments, because deeper levels of $variables are already preprocessed by core or might by contrib/custom code.